# Redirecting back from where user came from in ASP.NET User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control which overriding Page_load method, however what I want is, redirect user from where they came from, it can be on "ON INIT method" or any method as long as user is redirected.

This is what I got at the moment,

```
public partial class ASPUserControl: System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Lol well your clever, ain't you @TimSchmelter :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`UrlReferrer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx)

```
Uri previousUri = Request.UrlReferrer;
if(previousUri != null)
    Response.Redirect(previousUri.ToString());
```

However, the `UrlReferrer` is only populated if the user clicked on a link(f.e. via `PostBackUrl`) or similar, not if you've used `Response.Redirect` to go to this page. If you've used `Server.Transfer` you could use [`Page.PreviousPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx) to get the url.

Comment: Use the fully qualified name? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I don't understand the comment. [`Uri.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.tostring.aspx) works with `Response.Redirect`.

Comment: I thought he was missing a using.

Answer (score 0):

as long as he is requesting the page you can redirect user when/where ever you want onInit Page_Load or even a button click event. It is better if you can do it as early as possible to avoid unnecessary process.