# Redirecting back from where user came from in ASP.NET Page Not code behind

Tags: asp.net, html, http, sharepoint, redirect

I have a ASP.NET page what I got at the moment is

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="RedirectMeNow.aspx.cs" Inherits="abc.eyd._12.TEMPLATE.LAYOUTS.RedirectMeNow" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

how can I redirect a user back from where he came from here, not in code behind like here

[Redirecting back from where user came from in ASP.NET User Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397405/redirecting-back-from-where-user-came-from-in-asp-net-user-control/13397455#13397455)

> OR I just want a ASP.NET page that redirects user on call

Comment: I've removed the C# tag and added html since you insist on "no codebehind".

Comment: @TimSchmelter I changed my mind :) thanks tho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid using code-behind, you have to use a client-side Javascript function:

```
window.history.back();
```

You can either bind it to an event or execute it during page load.

EDIT:
If u want to make this page a redirect-only page, you can add this code to your  tag:

```
<head>
....
<script type="text/javascript>
window.history.back();
</script>
</head>
```

It will be executed as soon as page is getting loaded.
That's it!